# Is there a solution $x$ to the system $\sum_i p_i p_i^t x = p_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have $n$ vectors $p_k \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $k \in \{1,...,n\}$. I would like to prove, that there is always a vector $x_j$ that solves:

$$\sum_{i = 1}^n p_i \ p_i^t \ x_j = p_j \quad \forall \ j$$

The matrix $G = \sum_i p_i \ p_i^t$ may be singular, but is there a way to show that each $p_j$ is in the range of G? Or is there a counter example?

I thougt about something like: we take a set of $p_i $ that is linearly independent. That would span the range of $G$. And if we now find $p_i^tx = \delta_{ij}$... But I have no idea if that is the right way to go.

Comment: Show that if the $p_k$ are li. **iff** $\sum_k p_k p_k^T$ is invertible. This would give a sufficient condition.

Comment: those $p_k$ are not neccessarily linear independent, so $G$ can be singular. What do you mean by $iff$? My idea was to take a subset of the $p_k$ that is lin. indep. but that would not span the $\mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: iff is a standard abbreviation for if and only if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A= \sum_k p_k p_k^T$ and note that $Ax = 0 $ **iff** $p_k^T x = 0$ for all $k$.
In particular, $\ker A = \cap_k \ker p_k^T $ and so
${\cal R A} = (\ker A)^\bot = ( \cap_k \ker p_k^T )^\bot = \sum_k {\cal R p_k} = \operatorname{sp} \{ p_k \}_k$.

In particular, it is always true that $p_k \in {\cal R A}$.

Comment: Thank you! I first thought there could be another way to get $Ax = 0$ first but you are right. Since $x^Tp_kp_k^Tx$ is always non-negative, different parts of the sum cannot cancel out.